# Using onafterprint in Chrome & Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, safari

I am aware that until recently `onafterprint` was only native to IE.  Recently HTML5 has added it to its list of events.  I have only been successful in using it in Firefox but cannot get it to function in Chrome or Safari.

It appears to only function in Firefox when its used in the body:

```
<body onafterprint="printIt()">
```

The script for the function is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.printMe').click(function() {
    window.print();
    return false;
});
 });

function printIt()
{
$('#confirmPrint').show();
};
```

By clicking the `.printMe` button, it opens the print window.  Clicking print or cancel will show a message in `#confirmPrint`.  I'm not so worried about being able to tell whether they are clicking cancel or print. I am only concerned with it functioning in Chrome and Safari.  Any help is much appreciated.  I am using jQuery as well, if that is not already obvious.

Answer (score 1):

After some experiments, I think I can safely say that `onafterprint` is not worth considering.

- Firefox fires it even if the user clicked `Cancel` instead of `OK` in the print dialog
- IE8 apparently fires it even **before** the print dialog appears
- Chrome doesn't fire it at all

Instead, just do whatever you wanted to do directly after calling `print()`, i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.printMe').click(function() {
    window.print();
    printIt();
    return false;
  });
});

function printIt()
{
$('#confirmPrint').show();
};
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. In chrome if I have window.close() directly after window.print() the window closes before the user has an opportunity to interact with the print dialog.  `setTimeout(function(){ window.close() }, 0)` is now needed for chrome to allow the print dialog to finish before closing the window.