# Checking window.print() for successfully showing print dialog

Tags: asp.net, javascript

In my ASP.NET webpage code, I recently did this with `Javascript`:

```
if(!window.print())
  CallFunctionToWriteMessageToPage();
```

It  used to work fine but now it is not working. I looked up the Javascript `print()` function definition. It is not returning a bool.

Is it the right way to do what I want?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, to know when the user has printed (not possible), to know just that the print dialog is open (I think not possible also), or to know when the user focus is back on the page after print() is called (this is possible)?

Comment: @DavidKhaykin According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onafterprint it is possible to know when the user has printed. - on some browsers..

Comment: If the print dialog is not displayed (in case the end-user is using javafx browser), the function `CallFunctionToWriteMessageToPage()` is called. This works as expected.

Comment: Interesting point - wasn't aware of that and I had searched on the issue recently; however is that available in Chrome, IE, Safari, etc. also?

Comment: @KSK `!window.print() == !undefined == true`

Comment: @DavidKhaykin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893888/using-onafterprint-in-chrome-safari - so not the solution, but the event is there.. ;)